# extract the value of id as a string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is my code

```
<div class="row-fluid" id="header"></div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab2">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="span9 offset1">
                    <header id="second">
                        <strong>Users</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                <div class="tabbable" align="center">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#mobile" data-toggle="tab"><strong>Mobile</strong>
                        </a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#BO" data-toggle="tab"><strong>BO</strong>
                        </a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div></div></div>
```

Actually I want to extract the id BO as a string. Suppose there is some function called

```
function display(type){

 if (type== /* here I want to extract id BO */)
}
```

How can I do that I want to equate id BO to string type. using jquery or javascript.

```
function dislpay(type) {
```

/* here below in place of type I have to pass ids mentioned above using if function how can I do it this code is written in javascript*/

```
            $.get('http://something' + **type**, function(data) {
                 for ( var i = 0; i < data.user.length; i++) {
                    var html = '';
                    if (i == 0)
                        html = '<li class="active"><a href="#userdetails" data-toggle="tab" onclick=\"loadUserDetails(\''
                                + data.user[i].id
                                + '\')\">'
                                + data.user[i].id
                                + '</a></li>';
                    else
                        html = '<li><a href="#userdetails" data-toggle="tab" onclick=\"loadUserDetails(\''
                                + data.user[i].id
                                + '\')\">'
                                + data.user[i].id
                                + '</a></li>';

                    $("#users").append(html);
                }
                users = data; 
            })
             .error(function(xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error");
                alert(xhr.responseText);
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }); 

        }
```

Comment: who calls the function `display`?

Comment: Where you close your `</header>` ??

Comment: `/* here i want to extract id BO */` parting from where? instead of a supposed function include your actual code so we know what your actually trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function display(lnk) {
    if($(lnk).attr('href') == '#BO') {
     console.log(true);
    }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.nav-pills a').each(function(k,v) {
        display(this);
    });
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/cmEXb/

Comment: P.S. Writing and maintaining code it's good practice to define your functions before are being used.

Comment: Also `.each` by simply using `a` is a tremendous overhead. A better thing would be to restrict the `a` results to a parent `ID` (`#header`)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("*[data-toggle='tab']").click(function(){
        var type = "something";
        display(type, $(this).attr('href'));
    });
});


function display(type, href) {
    if (type == href) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In you HTML, `BO` isn't the `id`, its the `href` attribute. You can extract this using the following line:

`var ref=$(this).attr('href');`